# Dynamically fill field based on select from another field

Tags: html, vue.js, pug

I am trying to setup a form and have name and id auto fill in when a value is selected from customer Id.
the v-for is an array of objects with name, id, and company id

```
        .form-field
          label(for="customer_name") Customer name
          input(type="text" autocomplete="off" v-model="customer_name" readonly)
        .form-field
          label(for="customer.customer_id") Customer ID
          select(type="number" autocomplete="off" v-model="customer_id")
            option(v-for="id in customers") {{id.customer_Id}}
        .form-field
          label(for="company_id") Company ID
          input(v-model="company_id" readonly)
```

is there an easy way to do this in the html or would this require additional code in Vue?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than bind the `<select>` menu to the selected customer's Id (with `v-model`), instead bind it to the entire customer object, then you have easy access to the `selectedCustomers` name, id, etc:

```
   .form-field
      label(for="customer_name") Customer name
      input(type="text" autocomplete="off" v-model="selectedCustomer.name" readonly )
    .form-field
      label(for="customer_id") Customer ID
      select(autocomplete="off" v-model="selectedCustomer")
        option(v-for="customer in customers" :value="customer" :key="customer.customer_Id") {{customer.name}}
    .form-field
      label(for="company_id") Company ID
      input(v-model="selectedCustomer.company_Id" readonly)
```

You'll need to create a property to store the `selectedCustomer` object:

```
data() { return {
   customers: [ ... ]
   selectedCustomer: {},
} },
```